# Rails console error: Error loading ~/.pryrc: Command: `continue` not found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console, pry-rails

When I use the rails console on my current laptop (on any rails project), I get the following error when the console starts up.

```
Rails console error: Error loading ~/.pryrc: Command: `continue` not found
```

The console still loads and operates correctly but I can't seem to figure out the cause of the error.

Here are the contents of .pryrc.

```
Pry.config.pager = false
Pry.config.color = true
Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue'
Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step'
Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next'
```

If I remove the third line and run rails console, the error I get a similar error that references 'step' instead. The error doesn't affect my ability to troubleshoot but I'd really like to understand the underlying issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think those commands are in default `pry`. try installing `pry-debugger`:

```
gem install pry-debugger
```

and then modify to:

```
if defined?(PryDebugger)
  Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'f', 'finish'
end
```

see [pry-debugger docs](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was installing `pry-nav` gem:

`gem install pry-nav`
-or- use `gem "pry-nav"` in the Gemfile

with `.pryrc`:

```
Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue' rescue nil
Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step' rescue nil
Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next' rescue nil
Pry.commands.alias_command 'f', 'finish' rescue nil
Pry.commands.alias_command 'r!', 'reload!' rescue nil
```